# Modulo in PHP does not give expected result

Tags: php, modulo

```
<?php
    echo (9000000000 % 1000);
?>
```

Returns 408, while I was expecting 0

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Kind regards

Comment: Nope https://3v4l.org/TEgms Also check if you have 32 or 64 bits computing.

Comment: What is wrong then? https://i.imgur.com/Zq68Plt.png

Comment: `echo 9000000000;` would have probably been able to give you a clue already ...

Answer (score 5):

This is probably due to your platform – I suspect it is a 32-bit platform with a `PHP_INT_MAX` of ~2bn. The variable will be converted to `int` prior to the modulo.

You can try `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` to find that out.

If you run it on 64 bit platforms you'd get the expected result of `0`. You can try using `fmod` instead of `%`.
`fmod(9000000000, 1000);`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php

For more information:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Note: The 9000000000 will be converted to a float number for use by fmod. If the numbers get much larger, then they can no longer be represented exactly. In this case, strings and the BCMath function bcmod can be used.